# Árvore de busca binária em C

Tags: c, algoritmo-de-busca, árvore-binária

Preciso usar uma árvore de busca binária para organizar dados. Em cada nó preciso ter ID e nome, porém não sei como colocar dois valores em um mesmo nó. 
A árvore que estou usando está da seguinte maneira:

```
struct No {
  int data;
  struct No *left;
  struct No *right;
};
typedef struct No No;
```

O que devo mudar para armazenar dois dados em cada nó?

Comment: No teu `No` tu já tem 3 "valores", só adicionar mais um: `char nome[50]` algo assim

Answer (score 0):

Basta adicionar os dados que quiser dentro dessa própria `struct`.

Por exemplo:

```c
struct No {
    int id;
    char nome[64];
    struct No *left;
    struct No *right;
};

typedef struct No No;
```